# Equivalent of PHP preg_match, substr in javaScript

Tags: javascript, tinymce

i'm makeing a tinyMce plugin that change word/letter space between highlighted text. My fn() looks like this:

```
function wordsLettersSpace(words, letters) {
    var inst = tinyMCE.activeEditor;
    var currSelection = $.trim(inst.selection.getSel());

    if(currSelection != ""){
        var content = "";
        content = inst.selection.getContent({
            format: 'html'
        });

        contentReplace = '<span style="word-spacing: '+words+'px; letter-spacing: '+letters+'px;">' + inst.selection.getContent({
            format: 'html'
        }) + '</span>';

        inst.selection.setContent(content.replace(content, contentReplace));
        window.alert(content);
    }else{
        Hyphenator.hyphenate(inst.getBody(), language);
    }
    tinyMceUpdate();
}
```

Now i need to find closest  tag before select start position (if exist) and get style values of "word-spacing" and "letter-spacing". Also i need to get rid of any  inside of selection, but only tags not the text, knowing that span tags can have different styles so simple str.replace won't work.

I know that there is a built-in plugin for that, but i need to do it outside of tinyMce iframe, and customize it.

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS regexes are available and do exactly what you want with preg_match.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Substring in javascript is `str.substr(start, length)`

Comment: +1, although to be pedantic about it, the regex engine in JS has slightly different capabilities to the one in PHP. But for the most part, yes, `str.match(/regex/)` will do much the same as `preg_match()` in PHP.